# working with dates

Tags: php, date

I was wondering if anyone would help with the following:

I have a date called into a function in php. I need to estrapolate the month form this date in order to make some calculation base on the month only.

I really have no idea how do go about it. I have tried few things but none works.

It there anyone who can give a clue?

Appreciated any little help.
Francesco

Comment: Date format is YYYY/MM/DD as it is stored in Mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple

```
$month= date('n',strtotime($input));
```

Comment: Thank you molevna. Your suggestion worked perfectly.

I was thinking this: instead of using month if I want to use a starting day and a ending day (es 01/07 and 31/08) how would in this go?
Francescco

Comment: If date comparison is all you want to achieve, then resort to timestamp comparison, i.e. 

if(strtotime($input1)< strtotime($input2){ //input2 is later than input1 }

If you want to compare days of week or months - use same 'date' function with corresponding format parameters ('j' for day of the week in numerical format, and 'n' for month)

Answer (score 2):

You need a [unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp) to extract that information. Either you already have such a value, or you can get it using [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) on a string. The function you need to extract the month is [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
date('n', $timestamp);
```

Comment: strftime() is better than date as it is locale aware

Comment: date() is acceptable here, as I believe author is trying to extract month from standart gregorian calendar and it has 12 months in all locales.

Comment: @iAn: Wrong. strftime does not work in this case, since it left-pads single-digit integers with a 0, making PHP treat them as octals.

Comment: You have intrepreted "calculation" as a purely mathematical operation, in which case an octal value may cause problems, whereas intepretted as a logical operation, in which case it won't

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two steps: firstly convert the your input string into a datetime object PHP can work with, and secondly, extract the month from that dateime.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($inputDate);
$month = strftime("%m", $timestamp);
```

This would give you the month as a two digit number. There are more options in the full [documentation for strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

strtotime() should cope with the vast majority of date formats automatically. If it can't cope with your input then you need to use [strptime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) and pass in your exact format

Comment: The second line should be `$month = date('n', $timestamp);`. When trying to parse the numbers '01' through '09', PHP treats them as octal numbers, not decimal. date('n') returns the month without a left-padded 0.