# dates from and to

Tags: php, date

Hi I have already asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686961/working-with-dates). but want to make a change like this:

I have a starting date and ending date called into a function in php. I need to estrapolate the stating day and month form the startingDate and the same for the endingDate, so to make calculation based on day and month.

How do I go about this? Thank you thank you thank you. Francesco

Comment: Use PHP's date functions, especially date(): http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. Otherwise, please be more specific. What format is the date in? What have you tried?

Comment: The format is the Mysql format YYYY/MM/DD. What I tried is to exrapolate the month with:

$month = date('n',strtotime($startDate));

and it works. What I wish to do is to make a more specific result based on days and months.

Answer (score 0):

$start_month = date('m',$inStart);
$start_day = date('d',$inStart);

$end_month = date('m',$inEnd);
$end_day = date('d',$inEnd);

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method of the DateTime object build into PHP. Presuming you can turn startingDate and endingDate into DateTime objects (perhaps they already are), this will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could always break down the current date into a timestamp;

list($s_y, $s_m, $s_d) = explode('/', $start_date);
$start_date_ts = mktime(12, 12, 12, $s_m, $s_d, $s_y);

list($e_y, $e_m, $e_d) = explode('/', $end_date);
$end_date_ts = mktime(12, 12, 12, $e_m, $e_d, $e_y);

Then you'll have $end_date_ts and $start_date_ts, which you can compare and represent with ease.